# API call fails on my webhost

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-api

I m trying to retrieve data using the Yahoo API

This is the API that I m using to retrieve info

```
http://ff.search.yahoo.com/gossip?output=fxjson&command=QUERY
```

This is working on my Local server, but when I m using it in my web app. 
The query shows blank result. Can anyone tell me why is so happening. I tried searching it in the YDN forums. But I couldn't find suitable info about it !

Answer (score 0):

The ff.search.yahoo.com server is used for type-ahead search in browsers like Firefox. It's not an API, and I would not recommend developing anything that uses it. (In addition to possible terms of service violations, it may cease working or change at any time.)

As an alternative, you could use Yahoo's [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) service to select from the Search Suggestions search interface.

Here's an example query for the search term "soccer" (which you can try in the [YQL console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20k%20from%20yahoo.search.suggestions%20where%20command%3D%22soccer%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)):

`select k from yahoo.search.suggestions where command="soccer"`

Sample results:

```
{
 "query": {
  "count": 10,
  "created": "2012-10-21T01:16:15Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": {
   "s": [
    {
     "k": "soccernet"
    },
    {
     "k": "soccer games"
    },
    {
     "k": "soccer.com"
    },
    {
     "k": "soccer ball"
    },
    {
     "k": "soccer offices raided"
    },
    {
     "k": "soccer jerseys"
    },
    {
     "k": "soccer shoes"
    },
    {
     "k": "fox soccer channel"
    },
    {
     "k": "world cup soccer"
    },
    {
     "k": "mls soccer"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```